# How do I handle parallel pull requests for derived branches?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch, pull-request

My team wants me to create a separate pull request (with Bitbucket) for each logical change in a project so that it can be reviewed and approved easily.

I need to implement features A, B and C.

I created branch A, implemented the first change and created a pull request for A-->master. Now while I am waiting for review and approval I want to work on the next feature. I created a branch B derived from A.

```
master
      \
       A
        \
         B
```

Now I also finished implementing B and want to create another pull request for my team to review. If I do so (B-->master) it shows me both commits from A and B (which makes sense of course), but I don't want my team to review A again.

I know that I could make the second pull request B-->A but what will happen to this pull request if A is merged into master and deleted afterwards before B was merged into A?

**How can I have parallel pull requests that contain the changes for A and B but which are disjoint?**

Answer (score 1):

Make a branch for each feature. These are called *feature branches*. If you need to, branch off another branch. `git checkout feature/1; git branch feature/2`.

```
          D - E - F [feature/3]
         /
A - B - C [master]
         \
          G - H [feature/1]
               \
                I - J [feature/2]
```

You can submit `feature/2` and `feature/1` at the same time, so long as you make it clear that `feature/2` depends on `feature/1`.

> I know that I could make the second pull request B-->A but what will happen to this pull request if A is merged into master and deleted afterwards before B was merged into A?

If `feature/1` is revised and not yet merged, you should rebase `feature/2` on top of it with `git checkout feature/2; git rebase feature/1`. That would look like this, K and L are the new revisions.

```
          D - E - F [feature/3]
         /
A - B - C [master]
         \
          G - H - K - L [feature/1]
               \
                I - J [feature/2]
```

Then after `git checkout feature/2; git rebase feature/1` you'd have this:

```
          D - E - F [feature/3]
         /
A - B - C [master]
         \
          G - H - K - L [feature/1]
               \       \
                I - J   I1 - J1 [feature/2]
```

Then `git push --force` on feature/2. Note that the original changes are still there on your local repository after a rebase. They'll eventually be garbage collected, but meanwhile if you made a mistake you can get them back by examining `git reflog`.

Same procedure after `feature/1` has been merged and deleted (btw, you'll still have your local branch that you'll have to delete). Deleting a branch only deletes the label, the branch is still there (unless they "merge" by rebasing or squashing). You'll have this.

```
          D - E - F [feature/3]
         /
A - B - C ------------- M [master]
         \             /
          G - H - K - L
                       \
                        I1 - J1 [feature/2]
```

You should rebase `feature/2` onto master with `git rebase master`.

```
          D - E - F [feature/3]
         /
A - B - C ------------- M [master]
         \             / \
          G - H - K - L   I2 - J2 [feature/2]
```

And then `git push --force`.

Similarly, if `feature/3` is still under review you should rebase `feature/3` onto `master` to ensure it still works and to make the integrator's job easier.

---

If all this seems a little complicated, then submit `feature/1` and wait until after it's accepted and merged to submit `feature/2`. You should still do that last bit, rebase `feature/2` onto `master`.

Comment: What you mean by "submit"? Do you mean create pull request at the same time? What do you mean by "make clear"? Add a comment to the pull request? Also I am using Bitbucket, not Github, although this probably does not matter.

Comment: Yes and yes. I haven't used Bitbucket in a long time, but hopefully it will deal with rebasing a pull request well. Oh, I expanded the answer to cover your last part.

Comment: "_If all this seems a little complicated_" It does indeed. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a **master** branch.

- Create a new branch from master named A.
- Create a pull request for branch A
- Create another branch, B from branch A.

Now, since B was created from A, it will have the commits from A as well.
And even if A gets merged into the master branch and the pull request for branch A will close, the branch A still remains.

- So take a master rebase (**git rebase master**) on branch A
- And then take a rebase on branch B from A
- Finally take master rebase on branch B.

Comment: When exactly should I rebase A to master in the described workflow? I already branched A from master, so it will be fast forwarded anyway, wont' it?